How to display two lines' worth of text in div inside a Flexbox?
I have two divs inside a flexbox. The first div contains some dynamic content, and I want to display the first two rows worth of text. Currently, it only displays only one row. How can I make it display more rows?


.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  .flex-long {
    flex: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  .flex-short {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-long">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque commodo mi et venenatis fringilla. Curabitur id tempor tellus. Aliquam commodo feugiat velit ut gravida. Cras blandit, justo eget suscipit porttitor, odio nibh suscipit neque, tincidunt dictum urna purus et lorem. Maecenas lacinia molestie dui quis varius
  </div>
  <div class="flex-short">
    Read more
  </div>
</div>



Current output:

Expected :


the css nesting is quite recent in terms of adoption https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Nesting_selector and the & selector not mandatory for such condition where the nested rules have selectors that can be combined to the parent with whitespaces

talking strictly about the question, calling the first column of the the flexbox container something multiline is misleading. I mean is still a column that may have multiline text of course.. but the reason why you don't see it in its entirety it's just because you are using white-space: nowrap and it doesn't behave cropping a multiline content.. for that you'll need js that will explicitely crop the text according to its container width

as suggested in the answer given there's also the line-clamp css property that was formerly known as webkit-line-clamp and appearently having a fair support

You can add something like this CSS code to the inner divs, or perhaps you need to add another nested div for this. Here's the code:
.flex-long {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 6;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

